# InvalidOperationException: No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager has been registered error using ASP.NET Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to put all my data in one database, including business data and Identity data. So, I have run the migrations on my database and updated my DbContext.

I'm trying to modify my project from the New Project template for specified users in Blazor Web Assembly.

I run the app. It loads the home page. But, when I click Login, I receive the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[MyProject.Server.Models.ApplicationUser]'
> has been registered.

In my MyProject.Server Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();

    services.AddIdentityServer(
        options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        }
    )
    .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
    .AddConfigurationStore<MyContext>(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore<MyContext>(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    })
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, MyContext>();

    services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

There's nothing special in my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

And in my _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using MyProject.Server.Models
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

I didn't think I was trying to do anything special. The main thing is I am using a customer DbContext that overrides OnModelCreating. That is why I need to define so much of the IdentityServer.

Comment: You haven't got 2 different `ApplicationUser` classes by chance? Are you sure `MyContext` inherits from `IdentityContext<ApplicationUser>`?

Comment: Wow. You all are brilliant! I had 2 different ApplicationUser classes by accident from a copy/paste oversight. The _LoginPartial file was referencing the second one. Removing it entirely fixed everything.
For what it's worth, for me MyContext inherits from ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Comment: Glad it helped! Might be worth deleting the question now, it's not particularly useful to other users.

Comment: It won't let me delete the question.

Comment: Ah, the answer has a positive score. It needs to be zero or lower. You could downvote it I think, and then you will be able to delete after a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net core 5
add this :

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>();
```

according to the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dfcf1adee2c0f6c89ecf66a8791e550bce124698/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L48) this will register `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, that does not change anything. I have tried your exact suggestion as well as:
            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
                .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI();

Comment: @YeahStu which version of .net core you are using?

Comment: Please delete this answer so the question can be deleted by @YeahStu. This was never going to help solve it anyway.